Struct loses value in UnitTest
I came across a strange behavior and would like some clarification what's happening here.
I did create a simple immutable struct
public readonly struct MatchingPair : IEquatable<MatchingPair>
{
    private MatchingPair(Assets asset1, Assets asset2, bool validate = true)
    {
        if (validate)
        {
            InvalidMatchingPairException.ThrowIfEqualOrUnknown(asset1, asset2);
        }

        if (asset1 < asset2)
        {
            Asset1 = asset1;
            Asset2 = asset2;
        }
        else
        {
            Asset1 = asset2;
            Asset2 = asset1;
        }
    }

    public static MatchingPair Create(Assets asset1, Assets asset2)
    {
        return new MatchingPair(asset1, asset2);
    }

    internal static MatchingPair InternalCreate(Assets asset1, Assets asset2)
    {
        return new MatchingPair(asset1, asset2, false);
    }

    public Assets Asset1 { get; }
    public Assets Asset2 { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Asset1}<->{Asset2}";
    }

    public bool Equals(MatchingPair other)
    {
        return Asset1 == other.Asset1 && Asset2 == other.Asset2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is MatchingPair other && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine((int)Asset1, (int)Asset2);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MatchingPair left, MatchingPair right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MatchingPair left, MatchingPair right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
}

Assets is a simple enum nothing fancy.
After that I created an Exception class that will be raised when the Assets are invalid.
Lazy as I am I did not write every testcase instead I used the DynamicDataAttribute from the MSTestv2 Unit Test Framework.
However this does not work as expected because MatchingPair is losing it's values.
The minimal Test looks like
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(MatchingEngineExceptionConstructor4Data))]
public void MatchingEngineException_Constructor4_Test(string? message, MatchingPair? matchingPair, string expectedMessage)
{
    if (matchingPair.HasValue)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(Assets.Btc, matchingPair.Value.Asset1);
        Assert.AreEqual(Assets.Etc, matchingPair.Value.Asset2); // Fails unexpectedly
    }

    // ...actual test...
}

To create the test data I did the following
private static IEnumerable<object?[]> MatchingEngineExceptionConstructor4Data
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var message in new[] { null, "Céẞßö." })
        {
            var expectedMessage = message ?? "Error in the matching engine.";
            foreach (MatchingPair? matchingPair in new MatchingPair?[] { null, MatchingPair.Create(Assets.Btc, Assets.Etc) })
            {
                if (matchingPair != null) { expectedMessage += $" (MatchingPair '{matchingPair}')"; }

                yield return [message, matchingPair, expectedMessage];
            }
        }
    }
}

However, in the Unittests both Asset Properties are set to Assets.Btc which can only mean that they are set to the default value (0). But I would have expected them to hold the actual values I did set. The values are set correctly the expectedMessage I put together is proof of it since it shows the correct values.
Can someone bring some light to what is happening here.
I guess a possible fix is to convert the struct into a class, but I want to avoid that.

Is the problem with the null MatchingPair, or the initialised one? If you do foreach (MatchingPair? matchingPair in new MatchingPair?[] { MatchingPair.Create(Assets.Btc, Assets.Etc) }), what happens?

You might want to prevent that the default value of the enum has an actual business relevance beyond the meaning of something like "none", "uninitialised" etc. Not doing so often ends in having unexpected problems and has a smell.

@canton7 The problem is with the initialized one. The null value is working as expected.

@Ralf Good point, I did already change the enum to start with 1.

@canton7 Deleting the null only leads to less test cases. The error remains.

Cool, I wondered whether it might be an issue to do with null being unboxed incorrectly, but glad we can rule that out

have you tried debugging / alternatively posting all the code that would help others debug

@JHBonarius Assets is an Enum so they are just some Values in the Enum. The only thing we might check if he shows the definition is that he didn't use the same backing values for Etc and Btc.

Possible dupe

I've confirmed this seems to be a bug in MSTest.
I've changed the test to run on xUnit and there it doesn't fail.
I've made a github issue on the MSTest repo
offtopic: did you know you could get the IEquatable stuuf for free by making MatchingPair a record (you can keep the readonly struct).
Update
Like this answer and it's comment states: in MSTest 2.2.4 they added some behavior to the discovery of types, so now the each struct needs to implement ISerializable to be able to be discovered. It doesn't even matter what you put in the body of ISerializable.GetObjectData!
but IMHO it's not good that you should (have to) alter core code to accommodate for a test.
In 2.2.6 they added a way to opt-out (I thin kit should be opt-in), by setting the assembly-level(!) attribute [assembly: TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution)] (e.g. put it in the file AssemblyInfo.cs)

ad offtopic: Yes I know but than it would be a class not a struct :)
I can confirm that this is realy the case: After implementing ISerializable the error disappers.
Using xUnit instead works as well.

The opt out with attribute is working too. btw

@IamanSwtrse no, a readonly record struct is also a thing. Look it up

I just want to post my solution after a day trying to do this without the optout and keep the struct untouched in an "not ugly" way.
First this is the final struct
namespace Cobra.Exoda.Matching;

using Properties;

public readonly record struct MatchingPair
{
    [Obsolete("You may not use the parameterless constructor. Use MatchingPair.CreateAndValidate instead.", true)]
    public MatchingPair()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.Arg_MatchingPair_ParameterlessConstructorException);
    }

    private static Tuple<Assets, Assets> Initialize(Assets asset1, Assets asset2, bool validate)
    {
        if (validate) { InvalidMatchingPairException.ThrowIfEqualOrUnknown(asset1, asset2); }

        if (asset1 < asset2 || !validate) //If not validated do not change order as well.
        {
            return new Tuple<Assets, Assets>(asset1, asset2);
        }

        return new Tuple<Assets, Assets>(asset2, asset1);
    }

    private MatchingPair(Assets asset1, Assets asset2, bool validate)
    {
        Tuple<Assets, Assets> pair = Initialize(asset1, asset2, validate);
        Asset1 = pair.Item1;
        Asset2 = pair.Item2;
    }

    public static MatchingPair CreateAndValidate(Assets asset1, Assets asset2)
    {
        return new MatchingPair(asset1, asset2, true);
    }

    internal static MatchingPair InternalCreate(Assets asset1, Assets asset2)
    {
        return new MatchingPair(asset1, asset2, false);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Asset1}<->{Asset2}";
    }

    public Assets Asset1 { get; }
    public Assets Asset2 { get; }
}

The obsolete attribute prevents the parameterless contructor to be executed so
new MatchingPair() or new MatchingPair{Asset1 = 0, Asset2 = 0} is not working. That leaves MatchingPair p = default; as the only way to initialize the struct with invalid asset pairs.
Of course, unit tests fail now because the values of the properties get lost. To prevent this, I created a helper struct in the Test project. This struct is serializable and solves the problem with tests using DynamicData attribute.
namespace Cobra.Exoda.Matching.Tests.Helper;

using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public readonly record struct DataDrivenMatchingPair(Assets Asset1, Assets Asset2)
{
    public static implicit operator MatchingPair(DataDrivenMatchingPair dataDrivenMatchingPair)
    {
        return MatchingPair.CreateAndValidate(dataDrivenMatchingPair.Asset1, dataDrivenMatchingPair.Asset2);
    }
}

Inside the unit test you can now simply cast the DataDrivenMatchingPair to MatchingPair or if you call an underlying method you do not even have to explicitly cast it.
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(MatchingEngineExceptionConstructor4EnglishData))]
public void MatchingEngineException_Constructor4_English_Test(string? message, DataDrivenMatchingPair? matchingPair, string expectedMessage)
{
    MatchingEngineException_Constructor4_Test(message, matchingPair, expectedMessage);
}

private static void MatchingEngineException_Constructor4_Test(string? message, MatchingPair? matchingPair, string expectedMessage)
{
    // Arrange
    // Act
    var ex = new MatchingEngineException(message, matchingPair);
    // Assert
    if (matchingPair == null) { Assert.IsNull(ex.MatchingPair); }
    else { Assert.AreEqual(matchingPair, ex.MatchingPair); }

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, ex.Message);
    Assert.IsNull(ex.InnerException);
}

